# readline(argument) lead to "TypeError: str to integer" but the format change was not supposed

Tags: python, string, file, integer, typeerror

I have some shitty code, but I'm just curious with this type of error: "**TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**", when **readline()** was executed in **for** cycle. I was not going to change the format. This string '**number = num.readline(line)**' is wrong itself, but I thought about another types of errors, **so why format error**? All values in file are str, and line is str too.

```
def main():
    num = open('number_list.txt', 'r')

    for line in num:
        number = num.readline(line)
        print(number)

    num.close()
main()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline expects an *int* argument, you are passing a string. Try: `for line in num: print(line)`.

Comment: for line in num. line is equal to the actual line, not it's index. So we can just print line